# Как правильно получить массив байт по TCP/IP?

Tags: java, android, io

Есть сервер, который по команде присылает некоторое количество байт. Объём данных заранее известен - 280 Кбайт. Данные передаются через Wi-Fi сеть по TCP/IP соединению. Используется собственный протокол, который никак не отображает кол-во передаваемой информации. Вся ̶п̶р̶о̶б̶л̶е̶м̶а̶  особенность сервера в том, что он открывает поток (stream) и передает информацию фреймами разного размера. Размер каждого фрейма может колебаться в пределах от 10 до 2048 байт. Он будет передавать фреймы, пока не передаст весь объем данных (280 Кбайт). Другими словами, при приёме данных на Android-устройстве я никак не могу определить объем получаемых данных в потоке, соответственно, не могу разместить все данные в правильном виде.

**Вопрос:** Как правильно реализовать приём данных при таких "особенностях"?

**Возможное решение:** Я решил попробовать создать массив размером 2048 (максимально возможный размер фрейма) байт и записывать каждый новый фрейм в этот массив:

```
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
din.read(buffer);
```

Далее данные из моего `buffer` массива я пробовал помещать в коллекцию `ArrayList`, однако здесь возникла другая проблема: как определить, где закончились нужные данные, которые я сохранил в массив `buffer`?

Comment: если размер известен, можете создать массив нужного размера и вызвать [`DataInputStream.readFully`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully-byte:A-). Вообще, это не "особенность сервера", а так tcp работает.

Comment: Метод [read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read(byte[])) возвращает количество прочитанных в буфер байтов. Соответственно, это число нужно сохранять в переменную, после чего передавать такое количество байтов из буфера куда нужно.

Comment: @Regent и правда, что-то я не обратил внимание, что метод `read` ещё что-то возвращает. Спасибо! А не подскажите, как правильно в моём случае поступить с обработкой массива? Каждый новый полученный массив byte[] приводить к виду Byte[] и помещать в коллекцию или сразу создать огромный массив ( а именно `byte[] array = new byte[1024 * 280]`) и помещать данные туда?

Comment: @Denis422 если вы заранее знаете количество передаваемых данных и они вам все нужны, то имеет смысл создать один большой массив (как указанный `array`), после чего записывать в него блоками считанные байты. Привязывать сюда списки - лишняя трата памяти и лишние неудобства (придётся ведь ещё для каждого считанного "куска" хранить его реальный размер). Так что я за `new byte[1024 * 280]` и `System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, array, arrayPointer, readCount)`.

Comment: @Regent благодарю, можете оформить как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как вы заранее знаете объём передаваемых данных, то имеет смысл создать один большой массив (если полученные данные вам нужны целиком), после чего записывать в него блоками считанные байты.

Определить количество считанных в буфер байтов можно по числу, возвращаемому методом [read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)).

Привязывать сюда списки - лишняя трата памяти и лишние неудобства (придётся ведь ещё для каждого считанного "куска" хранить его реальный размер).

Схематичный код чтения данных блоками и запись в результирующий массив:

```
public byte[] read(Socket socket) throws IOException
{
    byte[] array = new byte[280 * 1024];
    int arrayPointer = 0;
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int readCount;
    while ((readCount = din.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, array, arrayPointer, readCount);
        arrayPointer += readCount;
    }
    return array;
}
```